# searching and splitting a list

Tags: python, list, formatting

I am trying to search through a list of hex values and split them out into separate lists when I see a '55'. The list of hex values looks like this

```
['55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'f0', '05', '91',
 '73', '06', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '44', '00', 'fd', '55',
 '00', '0a', '07', '01', 'eb', 'd2', '00', '48', 'ff', 'ff', '01', 'a8',
 '90', '6d', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '38', '00', '3c', '55',
 '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '02', '00', '30',
 '05', '80', 'df', '10', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '4a', '00',
 '52', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '02', '40', '05',
 '0b', '23', '48', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '50', '00', 'c1',
 '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '00', '00', '00',
 '00', '05', '80', 'ba', 'db', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '47',
 '00', 'd9', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '01', '30',
 '01', '9a', 'c0', '56', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '40', '00',
 'f6', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'b0', '05',
 '82', 'e1', '76', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '58', '00', '27',
 '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '03', '00',
 '30', '05', '80', 'df', '27', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '52',
 '00', 'f8']`.
```

Using the code below I am only getting the last list.

```
for x in line:
    if x == '55':
        count+=1
        linetwo = x
    else:
        linetwo += x
print(linetwo)
```

i.e. the output is `55000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8`

but I would like `['550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd', '55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c'....` etc etc, to be output

Comment: you should print your line each time you encounter a 55, not just at the end

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way of solving the problem can be this

```py
def splitList(a):
    combined = "|".join(a)
    splitString = combined.split("55")
    response = [f'55{splitPart.replace("|", "")}' for splitPart in splitString[1:]]
    return response
```

Where `a` is the following list:

```py
['55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'f0', '05', '91', '73', '06', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '44', '00', 'fd', '55', '00', '0a', '07', '01', 'eb', 'd2', '00', '48', 'ff', 'ff', '01', 'a8', '90', '6d', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '38', '00', '3c', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '02', '00', '30', '05', '80', 'df', '10', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '4a', '00', '52', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '02', '40', '05', '0b', '23', '48', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '50', '00', 'c1', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '05', '80', 'ba', 'db', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '47', '00', 'd9', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '01', '30', '01', '9a', 'c0', '56', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '40', '00', 'f6', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'b0', '05', '82', 'e1', '76', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '58', '00', '27', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '03', '00', '30', '05', '80', 'df', '27', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '52', '00', 'f8']
```

Result:

```
['550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd', '55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c', '55000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052', '550009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c1', '55000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9', '550009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6', '550009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff580027', '55000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `itertools.groupby` as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby
lst = ['55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'f0', '05', '91',
 '73', '06', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '44', '00', 'fd', '55',
 '00', '0a', '07', '01', 'eb', 'd2', '00', '48', 'ff', 'ff', '01', 'a8',
 '90', '6d', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '38', '00', '3c', '55',
 '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '02', '00', '30',
 '05', '80', 'df', '10', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '4a', '00',
 '52', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '02', '40', '05',
 '0b', '23', '48', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '50', '00', 'c1',
 '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '00', '00', '00',
 '00', '05', '80', 'ba', 'db', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '47',
 '00', 'd9', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '01', '30',
 '01', '9a', 'c0', '56', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '40', '00',
 'f6', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'b0', '05',
 '82', 'e1', '76', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '58', '00', '27',
 '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '03', '00',
 '30', '05', '80', 'df', '27', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '52',
 '00', 'f8']

for key, values in groupby(lst, lambda x: x == '55'):
    if not key:
        output = "55" + "".join(values)
        print(output)
```

Which would yield

```
550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd
55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c
55000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052
550009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c1
55000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9
550009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6
550009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff580027
55000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `linetwo` each time you reach a new `'55'`, you should append your results to a list as you generate them instead of discarding the previous result:

```
line = ['55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'f0', '05', '91', '73', '06', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '44', '00', 'fd', '55', '00', '0a', '07', '01', 'eb', 'd2', '00', '48', 'ff', 'ff', '01', 'a8', '90', '6d', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '38', '00', '3c', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '02', '00', '30', '05', '80', 'df', '10', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '4a', '00', '52', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '02', '40', '05', '0b', '23', '48', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '50', '00', 'c1', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '00', '00', '00', '00', '05', '80', 'ba', 'db', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '47', '00', 'd9', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '01', '30', '01', '9a', 'c0', '56', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '40', '00', 'f6', '55', '00', '09', '07', '01', '56', 'd2', '40', '00', 'b0', '05', '82', 'e1', '76', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '58', '00', '27', '55', '00', '0c', '07', '01', '96', 'd2', '40', '00', '20', '03', '00', '30', '05', '80', 'df', '27', '00', '00', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', 'ff', '52', '00', 'f8']

out = []
linetwo = ""
count = 0
for x in line:
    if x == '55':
        count+=1
        if linetwo:
            out += [linetwo]
        linetwo = x
    else:
        linetwo += x
out += [linetwo]
print(out)
# ['550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd', '55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c', '55000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052', '550009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c1', '55000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9', '550009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6', '550009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff580027', '55000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8']
```

---

Alternatively you can use `join`, `split` and `map`:

```
out = list(map(lambda i: "55" + i,"".join(line).split("55")[1:]))
```

The `join` merges all of the data together:

```
550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c55000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052550009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c155000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9550009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6550009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff58002755000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8
```

The `split` and slice (`[1:]`) separate the data and remove the preceeding empty element:

```
['0009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd',
 '000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c',
 '000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052',
 '0009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c1',
 '000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9',
 '0009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6',
 '0009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff580027',
 '000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8']
```

And the `map` reattaches the `55`s to the beginning of each (The `list` call just converts it from a `map` object back into a `list` for printing).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a generator which takes a predicate, like this:

```
def slice_at(predicate, iterable):
    i, x, size = 0, 0, len(iterable)
    while i < size-1:
        if predicate(iterable[i+1]):
            yield iterable[x:i+1]
            x = i + 1
        i += 1
    yield iterable[x:size]
```

Then you can call it passing the required operation to apply:

```
# lst = your list
tmp = slice_at(lambda x: x == '55', lst) # this return the sliced list (generator)
res = [ ''.join(x) for x in tmp ] # this joins the sublists
```

The result is:

```
# ['550009070156d24000f0059173060000ffffffff4400fd',
#  '55000a0701ebd20048ffff01a8906d0000ffffffff38003c',
#  '55000c070196d24000200200300580df100000ffffffff4a0052',
#  '550009070156d2400240050b23480000ffffffff5000c1',
#  '55000c070196d24000000000000580badb0000ffffffff4700d9',
#  '550009070156d2400130019ac0560000ffffffff4000f6',
#  '550009070156d24000b00582e1760000ffffffff580027',
#  '55000c070196d24000200300300580df270000ffffffff5200f8']
```